# LangChain search_tools ValueError: ('Searx API returned an error: ', 'Too Many Requests')

Tags: python-3.x, agent, py-langchain

When I run the following example code, I get this error:

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
 I need to find out what the current weather is
Action: searx_search
Action Input: "weather in Pomfret"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\computer_science\3.1.Improve_organization_talent_continuously\1.AIaaS\LangChain\agent_search.py", line 35, in <module>
    agent.run("What is the weather in Pomfret")
  File "E:\program_interpreter\python_virtual_environment\learn_ai\LangChain\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 487, in run
    return self(args[0], callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
  File "E:\program_interpreter\python_virtual_environment\learn_ai\LangChain\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 292, in __call__
    raise e
  File "E:\program_interpreter\python_virtual_environment\learn_ai\LangChain\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 286, in __call__
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
  File "E:\program_interpreter\python_virtual_environment\learn_ai\LangChain\lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1122, in _call
    next_step_output = self._take_next_step(
  File "E:\program_interpreter\python_virtual_environment\learn_ai\LangChain\lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 977, in _take_next_step
    observation = tool.run(
  File "E:\program_interpreter\python_virtual_environment\learn_ai\LangChain\lib\site-packages\langchain\tools\base.py", line 356, in run
    raise e
  File "E:\program_interpreter\python_virtual_environment\learn_ai\LangChain\lib\site-packages\langchain\tools\base.py", line 328, in run
    self._run(*tool_args, run_manager=run_manager, **tool_kwargs)
  File "E:\program_interpreter\python_virtual_environment\learn_ai\LangChain\lib\site-packages\langchain\tools\searx_search\tool.py", line 31, in _run
    return self.wrapper.run(query, **self.kwargs)
  File "E:\program_interpreter\python_virtual_environment\learn_ai\LangChain\lib\site-packages\langchain\utilities\searx_search.py", line 365, in run
    res = self._searx_api_query(params)
  File "E:\program_interpreter\python_virtual_environment\learn_ai\LangChain\lib\site-packages\langchain\utilities\searx_search.py", line 277, in _searx_api_query    
    raise ValueError("Searx API returned an error: ", raw_result.text)
ValueError: ('Searx API returned an error: ', 'Too Many Requests')
```

The example code can be found here:

https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/docs/docs_skeleton/docs/integrations/tools/search_tools.ipynb

My code is as below:

```py
# Step3.select your tools
tools = load_tools(["searx-search"], searx_host="https://search.bus-hit.me/", llm=llm)

# Step4.init your agent
agent = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True)

# Step5.run your question by agent:What is the weather in Pomfret
agent.run("What is the weather in Pomfret")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting locally - make sure that you have *server.limiter* set to *false* and json is included in search.formats. These parameters can be defined in

> searxng/settings.yml

```
server:
 limiter: false
general:
 debug: true
search:
 formats:
  - html
  - json
```